# Regular expression for field and value

Tags: regex

I've text as:

> field = a value = 1345   field = b value = 3453

I need regular expression so that I can extract data as:

```
field  value

a      1345

b      3453
```

What can be the perfect regex for it?

Answer (score 0):

The expression should be:

```
field\s=\s([^\s]+)\svalue\s=\s([^\s]+)
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/dT1jX9/1)

There are two capturing groups: one for field and one for value. Also note that I have specified any character other than space as a value for field or value - you could make it stricter.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
field\s*=\s*([^\s]+)\s*value\s*=\s*([^\s]+)
```

**[demo](https://regex101.com/r/dT1jX9/2)**

it fill up more than one spaces  case like `field = a value = 1345   field =  b value = 3453`